# ClassNotFoundException upon restoring GoogleMaps object state

Tags: android, google-maps, classloader, classnotfoundexception, android-savedstate

My app is crashing consistently when attempting to restore the state of my `GoogleMap` (`mapView`) object after returning from an Activity. `mapView` sits in a custom Support lib v4 `Fragment` (`MyFragment`), which itself is embedded in an `AppCompatActivity` (`MyActivity`). The setup of these components is normal. My device is developer-configured to destroy all `Activity`s upon push.

Upon pushing and popping another `Activity`, my `Fragment`'s `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle state)` method is called, and crashes on

```
  mapView.onCreate(state);
```

producing the trace at bottom.

The crash does *not* occur on first creation when `state` is `null`. The crash is not resolved by any combination (that I can find) of enabling or disabling MultiDex or Proguard.

Indeed, the only thing I can do to get the thing to work seems to be enabling Instant Run and running directly from Android Studio. In this case, everything is fine. If Instant Run is disabled and I run from Android Studio, the crash appears.

---

***Update:***

This past week, Google released Android Build Tools v5.0.1, and Google Play Services v10.0. After updating, this problem seems to have cleared itself up. I will leave this question open however for the record to see if any other ideas present themselves. Aлекс's idea below is a good one that I may try regardless.

---

```
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  : Class not found when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$SavedState
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$SavedState
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.os.Bundle.getBundle(Bundle.java:763)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at aby.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:74)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at maps.ad.t.a(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at maps.ad.R.a(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at xx.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:66)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapViewDelegate$zza$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$3.zzb(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zzbsp(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at com.myco.myapp.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.java:235)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2087)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1113)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1277)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2154)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:603)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:181)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at com.myco.myapp.main.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:176)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1266)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6916)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$SavedState" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000018/DynamiteModulesB_GmsCore_prodmnc_hdpi_release.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000018/n/armeabi-v7a, /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000018/n/armeabi, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.DelegateLastPathClassLoader.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms:34)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  ... 44 more
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$SavedState
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
11-11 13:37:42.165 18389 18389 E Parcel  :      at java.lang.BootClass
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myco.myapp, PID: 18389
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myco.myapp/com.myco.myapp.main.MainActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$SavedState
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3255)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$SavedState
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2432)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Bundle.getBundle(Bundle.java:763)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at aby.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:74)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at maps.ad.t.a(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at maps.ad.R.a(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at xx.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:66)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapViewDelegate$zza$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$3.zzb(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zzbsp(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.myco.myapp.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.java:235)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2087)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1113)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1277)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2154)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:603)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:181)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.myco.myapp.main.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:176)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1266)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6916)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
11-11 13:37:42.170 18389 18389 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 9 more
11-11 13:37:42.175  2546  3527 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.myco.myapp/.main.MainActivity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your map's state in a separate bundle, then put this bundle as a field  into your fragment's state bundle.
When restoring your fragment's state, extract the map's bundle from the fragment's restore state bundle and send it to the map's restore state method.